# How to remove the onclick function and enable it using the same function through jquery?

Tags: jquery, onclick, disable-link

I am having the following code.What I am trying to acheive is when I click 1 it shoould disable the 1 onclick function and remaining needs to be available.And when I click 2, the 1 and 3 needs the onclick function but 2 doesnt need it.

I needs to achieve like pagination.How can I do it.

```
<div class="test">
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="test1(1);">1</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="test1(2);">2</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="test1(3);">3</a>
</div>

function test1(val)
  {
    $(this).attr('onclick','').unbind('click');
            alert("hai");
  }
```

But I am getting each and every time the alert.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to disable the function on the last clicked button. You could do that this way:

```
<div class="test">
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="test1(1);">1</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="test1(2);">2</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="test1(3);">3</a>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
var lastClickedInt;
function test1(val)
  {
    if (val !== lastClickedInt) {
        lastClickedInt = val;
        alert("hai");
    }
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Best way to do it is by using classes and event delegation:

```
<div class="test">
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="test1(1);">1</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="test1(2);">2</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="test1(3);">3</a>
</div>

$('div.test').on('click','a',function(e) {
  if(!$(this).hasClass('disabled')) {
    //you're event delegation code
  }

  //disable this link and "enable" it's siblings
  $(this).addClass('disabled').siblings().removeClass('disabled');
});
```